# For every polynomial $P$ of degree not greater than 2012 $\underset{3\leq t \leq 4}{\max}|P(t)|\leq C \underset{0\leq t \leq 1}{\max}|P(t)|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, continuity, normed-spaces, maxima-minima

Can you help me with the following?

Prove that there exists constant $C$ such that for every polynomial $P$ of degree not greater than 2012 $\underset{3\leq t \leq 4}{\max}|P(t)|\leq C \underset{0\leq t \leq 1}{\max}|P(t)|$.

I know that set of polynomials on $[a,b]$ is subset of $C[a,b]$ and that $C[a,b]$ is isometric isomorph to $C[0,1]$ for every $a,b$. So,
$$ \underset{3\leq t \leq 4}{\max}|P(t)| = ||P||_{C[3,4]} = ||P||_{C[0,1]} = \underset{0\leq t \leq 1}{\max}|P(t)|,$$
so $C=1$.

I am very suspicious of this solution, can you tell me am I wrong and what should I do instead?
Thank you!

Comment: It is true that $C[a,b]$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C[0,1]$. However, that doesn't mean that $\|P\|$ under both norms is the same. It would mean that $\|P\|_{C[3,4]} = \|TP\|_{C[0,1]}$ where $T$ is the isomorphism corresponding to $C[3,4]$ (which is translation, perhaps).

Comment: $P(x) = x$ shows that your equation is wrong.

Comment: Oh, thank you, you are right. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The space of polynomials of degree less or equal $2012$ is finite dimensional  (dimension is equal $2013).$ All norms on this space are equivalent. In particular the norms $$\|P\|_1=\max_{0\le x\le 1}|P(x)|,\qquad  \|P\|_2=\max_{3\le x\le 4}|P(x)| $$  are equivalent. Therefore there is a constant $C$ satisfying the requirement. Moreover there is a constant $D$ such that $$\underset{3\leq t \leq 4}{\max}|P(t)|\geq D \underset{0\leq t \leq 1}{\max}|P(t)|$$

**Remark** For any $a<b$  we can interpret the polynomials as the subspace of $C[a,b]$ with norm $\|f\|_\infty =\displaystyle \max_{a\le x\le b}|f(x)|.$

Comment: Maybe you should explain why $\sup_{[0,1]}|p(t)|$ defines a norm on the space of polynomals of degree less than N. (There must be _something_ to be proved there, since for example it's not a norm on $C(\Bbb R)$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am afraid that giving too many details may be confusing.

Comment: Proving that these are norms seems pretty straightforward to me: $||P||_1=0 \implies P(t)=0, \forall t \in [0,1]$, so P has more than 2012 zeros, so must be zero polynomial. The other two conditions are trivial. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Edit:}$ As Ryszard Szwarc pointed out there was a mistake so now the second try.

I think and explicit constant is easy to access threw watching shifted polynoms
$$\underset{t \in [3,4]}{\max}|P(t)| = \underset{t \in [3,4]}{\max}|\sum_{k=0}^{2012}a_k\cdot t^k|=\underset{t \in [0,1]}{\max}|\sum_{k=0}^{2012}a_k \cdot(t+3)^k|\\=\underset{t \in [0,1]}{\max}|\sum_{k=0}^{2012}a_k \cdot \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}t^{k-i}3^i|$$
$$
\leq \underset{t \in [0,1]}{\max}|\sum_{k=0}^{2012}a_k\cdot t^k|+\underset{t \in [0,1]}{\max}| \sum_{k=0}^{2012}a_k \cdot\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i}t^{k-i}3^i| \\
\leq
\underset{t \in [0,1]}{\max}|P(t)|+ \sum_{k=0}^{2012}|a_k| \cdot\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i}3^i\\
$$
Choose a $C$ (only possible if $P(t)\neq0$) so that
$$(C-1)\cdot\underset{t \in [0,1]}{\max}|P(t)|\geq\sum_{k=0}^{2012}|a_k| \cdot\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i}3^i$$
to get your upper bound.

Comment: How do you justify the first inequality, where $t^{k-i}(-3)^i$ is replaced by $t^k3^i$ ?

Comment: Oops, I had the inequality about $t^k<t^i$ for $i<k$ and $0\leq t \leq 1$ wrong in mind.

Comment: I don't see where your statement contradicts my attempt. I get an inequality of the whole polynomial in terms of the same polynomial with different domain $\textbf{plus}$ a constant that depends on termwise estimation.

Comment: Sorry, only now I have noticed that after my first comment you have re-edited your answer.